# Extract Yelp's rating

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, yelp

I have this locations.json file where I store the titles, locations (lat, long), and phone numbers. The issue I'm facing right now might seem trivial to others but as a beginner I couldn't get it to work the way I like. I want to extract the ratings only from Yelp's api v3 and add it to the locations.rating array. The code I have below appends the whole response object return from Yelp, but when I tried to console.log (response.businesses[0].rating) it was able to print out only the rating. How do I make it return only the rating?  Thanks in advance.

```
var yelpPhoneSearch = "https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search/phone?phone=";
var cors_anywhere_url = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/';  // Yelp v3 api doesn't support CORS, need to use this 3rd party proxy service
var locations = [];
$.getJSON('/locations.json', function(data){
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var schools = {};
    schools.title = data[i].title;
    schools.location = data[i].location;
    schools.phone = data[i].phone;
    schools.rating = $.ajax({
      "async": true,
      "crossDomain": true,
      "url": cors_anywhere_url + yelpPhoneSearch + data[i].phone,
      "method": "GET",
      "headers": {
        "authorization": "Bearer " + yelpToken.access_token,
        "cache-control": "public, max-age=31536000",
      }
    }).done(function(response){
      // console.log(response);
      var rating = response.businesses[0].rating;
      return rating;
    });
    // Push all infos to locations array
    locations.push(schools);
  }
});
```

Comment: `it was able to print out only the rating. How do I make it return only the rating score?` how about an example of the data you receive ... what's the difference between `rating` and `rating score`

Comment: also, as AJAX (this included $.getJSON) is asynchronous, `schools.rating` will not be the value returned by `return rating;` it will be a jQuery promise of `response` (because you use .done)

Comment: If I run `console.log(JSON.stringify(locations[0].rating))` I get [this (pastebin. )](https://pastebin.com/WF5BbQZA)

 I'm not really familiar with jQuery promise, Is there any other way to push the yelp's rating into the locations array?

Comment: I still can't see what you mean by "rating score" - that's `response.businesses[0].rating` as far as I can tell (4.5 in your pastebin)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I just meant rating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using jQuery promises (which are almost like regular Promises except guaranteed to be available in old browsers) you can rewrite your code like so

```
var yelpPhoneSearch = "https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search/phone?phone=";
var cors_anywhere_url = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/';  // Yelp v3 api doesn't support CORS, need to use this 3rd party proxy service

$.getJSON('/locations.json')
.then(function(data){
    return $.when.apply($, data.map(function(school) {
        return $.ajax({
            "async": true,
            "crossDomain": true,
            "url": cors_anywhere_url + yelpPhoneSearch + school.phone,
            "method": "GET",
            "headers": {
                "authorization": "Bearer " + yelpToken.access_token,
                "cache-control": "public, max-age=31536000",
            }
        }).then(function(response) {
            return {
                title: school.title,
                location: school.location,
                phone: school.phone,
                rating: response.businesses[0].rating
            };
        });
    }));
}).then(function() {
    var locations = [].slice.call(arguments);
    /* here locations is an array of 
    {
        title,
        location,
        phone,
        rating
    }
    */
});
```

Note: because of the asynchronous nature of `$.ajax` you can't access the array of results outside of the last `.then` because asynchronous code is asynchronous

For completeness - ES2015+ with native Promises, the code would be

```
$.getJSON('/locations.json').then(data => 
    Promise.all(data.map(school => 
        $.ajax({
            "async": true,
            "crossDomain": true,
            "url": cors_anywhere_url + yelpPhoneSearch + school.phone,
            "method": "GET",
            "headers": {
                "authorization": "Bearer " + yelpToken.access_token,
                "cache-control": "public, max-age=31536000",
            }
        }).then(response => ({
            title: school.title,
            location: school.location,
            phone: school.phone,
            rating: response.businesses[0].rating
        }))
    ))
).then(locations => {
    /* here locations is an array of 
    {
        title,
        location,
        phone,
        rating
    }
    */
});
```

If you need to access `locations` in some other parts of your code, and assuming the code in your question is not taken from a function (i.e. the vars are all global scoped)

```
var yelpPhoneSearch = "https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search/phone?phone=";
var cors_anywhere_url = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/';  // Yelp v3 api doesn't support CORS, need to use this 3rd party proxy service

var locations = $.getJSON('/locations.json')
.then(function(data){
    return $.when.apply($, data.map(function(school) {
        return $.ajax({
            "async": true,
            "crossDomain": true,
            "url": cors_anywhere_url + yelpPhoneSearch + school.phone,
            "method": "GET",
            "headers": {
                "authorization": "Bearer " + yelpToken.access_token,
                "cache-control": "public, max-age=31536000",
            }
        }).then(function(response) {
            return {
                title: school.title,
                location: school.location,
                phone: school.phone,
                rating: response.businesses[0].rating
            };
        });
    }));
}).then(function() {
    return [].slice.call(arguments);
});
```

Now, in code where ever you need to use locations, you'll need to get access to the result using typical Promise methodology

```
locations.then(function(value) {
    // in here,  value is an array of locations
});
```

Without seeing how you are using `locations` in your actual code, this may not be as easy as above, because, once you deal with asynchronous code, you need to deal with it properly

Comment: I tried your code but now the locations array is empty.

Comment: well that's unfortunate - did you try to work with `locations` outside of the last .then or where I said `here locations is an array of`? when you say it's empty, do you mean it's length is zero?

Comment: The locations array is just used to created markers on Google Map. I just `console.log(locations)` at the global scope (not inside the `then` block) and its length is zero. Using my code the locations array has 24 objects.

Comment: right ... but **where** do you do this, inside the `.then` as I said you SHOULD, or outside it. because you get the rating asynchronously after getting the list of locations asynchronously, you can't synchronously access locations array outside the asynchronous code - that's how asynchronous code works

Comment: if you `console.log(locations)` just after `locations = [].slice ...` and it is zero length, that would suggest that `data` is zero length and that there were no requests made to `cors_anywhere_url`

Comment: note that I specifically used `var locations =` inside the last `.then` callback, to emphasise the scope of the results

Comment: You are correct, yelp's ratings were successfully pushed to the locations array. But the whole thing now would break my app, because `locations` is no longer a global variable which the app was depending on. How do I make it global again? Please tell.

Comment: you can't work with asynchronous results (locations in your case) in a synchronous way - let me edit the answer and show you how you may be able to mitigate the amount of code you need to change - though, without seeing how you use locations I'm only guessing

Comment: I've figured it out, using your advice. Now I had to move some of my code inside the `then` statement. This is my first time learning about Promises in JS. Thank you very much. I still need to study the code you wrote, some syntax I still haven't learned.